# How to display database results into a folder structure using JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, mongodb, directory

I have stored some data in Mongo DB (file name, URL, keywords) and performed search for particular files, I can display this result in JSP file line by line but my requirement is to display all the results in a folder structure. for example Java folder should contain Java related files.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

For display porpose you can make use of [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/)

> jsTree is a javascript based, cross browser tree component. It is
>   packaged as a jQuery plugin. jsTree is absolutely free (licensed same
>   as jQuery – under the terms of either the MIT License).

Comment: That's what it's written on the site. The sentence ends there. I am just quoting. :)